# C# SHA1 conversion don't match Swift SHA1

Tags: c#, swift, sha1

I'm trying to convert c# code to swift where I trying to convert a string to sha1 hash. I'm trying to achieve similar results in swift. However I'm getting different result. Can someone please point me in right direction, if I'm missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

C# code

```csharp
public static string toSha1Digest(this string str)
{
    using (SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {

        var mStr = "test1234";
        
        var uni = new byte[mStr.Length * 2];
        var encoder = Encoding.Unicode.GetEncoder();
        encoder.GetBytes(mStr.ToCharArray(), 0, mStr.Length, uni, 0, true);

        var hByte = sha1.ComputeHash(uni);

        var buildString = new StringBuilder();
        hByte.ToString();
        for (var i = 0; i < hByte.Length; i++)
        {
            buildString.Append(hByte[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        var convertedString = buildString.ToString();
        buildString = null;
        Array.Resize<byte>(ref uni, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(convertedString);
    }
}
```

prints

```
5387F24564B241075F48BBDFDDDC12640015E92A
```

Swift Code

```swift
import CommonCrypto

let data = "test1234".data(using: .utf8)
let digest = Insecure.SHA1.hash(data: data!)
print(digest.hexStr)

extension Digest {
    var bytes: [UInt8] { Array(makeIterator()) }
    var data: Data { Data(bytes) }

    var hexStr: String {
        bytes.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

prints

```
9BC34549D565D9505B287DE0CD20AC77BE1D3F2C
```

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF-16.

Comment: Do you mean for the C# code to always convert the string `test1234` and not the string argument passed to the function?

Comment: Also `Encoding` class has a `GetBytes` method that returns properly sized array on its own, no need to pre-allocate one and guess the size.

Comment: `.utf16LittleEndian` actually, and that gives the same result as your C# code.

Comment: I mean, you obviously use UTF-8 for the second snippet, the first one converts to UTF-16, yielding a different byte sequence, hence the different hash. Try `Encoding.UTF8` instead.

Comment: If you can, I suggest to change the C# code, because UTF-8 is more common as an encoding to calculate SHA-1 from: `var hByte = sha1.ComputeHash( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( str ) );`

Comment: For fun, here is an updated and MUCH faster implementation of the C# that also saves on memory allocations and produces no warnings in .Net 6: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HdOBG0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said in the comments, [`Encoding.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=net-6.0) gets an encoding for the UTF-16 format, more precisely: UTF-16 in little endian byte order, without byte order marker. The corresponding Swift `String.Encoding` is [`.utf16LittleEndian`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding/utf16littleendian), i.e. with

```
let data = "test1234".data(using: .utf16LittleEndian)
```

your Swift code produces the same hash as the C# program.

See it here:

> https://swiftfiddle.com/xhgvftigondzngqictf22jvzeq

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for adding the live demonstration!